# why does discord.py keep sending messages?

Tags: discord.py

i made an event that sends a message back if a user sends a specific message. **ex. if user says 'hello' the bot says 'hello there'**. I found that in the code below the first elif has an or..so if the user says ddos or hack it goes in an infinite loop and keep sending **you can't say that!**.If the user enters hello the bot sends **hello there** once then goes in an infinite loop and sends **you can't say that!**. Any ideas why?

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    msg = message.content.lower()
    if str(msg) == "hello":
        await message.channel.send('hello there')
    elif str(msg) == "hack" or "ddos":
        await message.channel.send("you can't say that!")
    else:
        return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a few mistakes. First one, you have to check if message author is bot, so `on_message` event won't check bot's messages. You can check it by `discord.Member.bot`. This will return True if member is bot.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
```

Second one is, `elif str(msg) == "hack" or "ddos":` is not equal to `elif str(msg) == "hack" or str(msg) == "ddos":`.

`elif str(msg) == "hack" or "ddos":` means if `msg` equals to **hack** or **ddos** exists. Also, you don't have to do `str(msg)`. `message.content` returns `str` type object.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    msg = message.content.lower()
    if msg == "hello":
        await message.channel.send('hello there')
    elif msg == "hack" or msg == "ddos":
        await message.channel.send("you can't say that!")
```

**EDIT**:

You can use `if msg in list:` to check if message content is in a list of words. Here's an example:

```py
if msg in ['hack', 'ddos']:
    await message.channel.send("you can't say that!")
```

This will do the same thing as:

```py
if msg == 'hack' or msg == 'ddos':
    await message.channel.send("you can't say that!")
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I didn't know you had to write **msg ==** again. Also do you know how I can check if the user typed something from a list? Like can I make a list of words then see if the word is in the list? If it is it sends them a message if it's not it returns. Would we use a for loop for this?